# type of html content http get returned in flutter

Tags: html, css, flutter, web

I am not frontend web developer, and
I am using google map inside web view in flutter application.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
uri = Uri.parse("[some google map url][1]");
var response = await http.get(uri);
debugPrint(response.body);
```

it prints something like this :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" lang="en"> <head> <link href="/maps/preview/opensearch.xml?hl=en" title="Google Maps" rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml"> <title>  Google Maps  </title> <meta content=" Find local businesses, view maps and get driving directions in Google Maps. " name="Description">  <meta content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"> <meta content="chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"> 
<meta content="notranslate" name="google"> <meta content="origin" name="referrer"> <meta content="ByHT0GXztW_RcGxS0o86DBf1WtNu02FfqlcT8njnSqU" name="google-site-verification"> <meta content="Diln__r3p9-tt39P2Cl2Amvx6oFB4PATnxuFBaw6ej8" name="google-site-verification">   <meta content="ثانوية زكي الأرسوزي to Faculty of Architecture" itemprop="name"> <meta content="ثانوية زكي الأرسوزي to Faculty of Architecture" property="og:title">  <meta content="https://maps.goo.......
```

the body of the response is not similar to the body shown in the same url in the browser inspector, can someone explain to me what is the difference between them please.
(I want to get the same html code in the browser in dart).

Comment: Do you wish to show the html code or map in the ui?

Comment: yes, I am showing the code, the main problem actually is that I am scraping the distance between  two locations,
when using querySelector on the browser (with android useragent added) it works, but it doesn't work with the web view for some reason

Comment: What you get in the http request is unrendered code, which you could see when you view page source (right click on page and `View Page Source` instead of inpect in console. 
This usually happens when the website used frameworks to build.

Comment: You might want to use library like Beautiful Soup (Python) or Puppeteer to scrape instead.